# xml XDocument from isolatedstorage, for use with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm having trouble in the following code, in that, the XDocument contains NO elements and hence the LINQ query will not execute.  I've posted the code and the XML below that.  For the life of me I cannot work out why, when the XDocument is populated (this is the xml I have provided from a copy & paste out of visual studio).  Any help as to why the Descendants will not find any of the elements I would be very grateful...  Regards, Tim.

**The Code**

```
// load all of the pictures into the list so we can see the details
IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(isoStore.OpenFile(App._PicturesConfig,System.IO.FileMode.Open));
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("Picture") 
select new Picture              
{                  
    Name = (string)query.Element("Name"),
    Date = (string)query.Element("Date"),                  
    Url = (string)query.Element("Url")              
};
lb_picListBox.ItemsSource = data;
```

**The XML Document:-**

```
<ArrayOfPicture xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Picture>
    <Name>FishCleaning</Name>
    <Date>20110905</Date>
    <Desc>Cleaning behaviour of blue-striped grunt and four-eyed butterfly fish, Florida Keys National Marine Sanctuary, USA -- Stephen Frink/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\FishCleaning20110905</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>Stephansdom</Name>
    <Date>20110904</Date>
    <Desc>Roof of the Stephansdom (St Stephen’s) Cathedral, Vienna, Austria -- Walter Bibikow/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\Stephansdom20110904</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>RegataStorica</Name>
    <Date>20110903</Date>
    <Desc>Historical regatta in Venice, Italy -- SIME/eStock Photo</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\RegataStorica20110903</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>PearlMonument</Name>
    <Date>20110902</Date>
    <Desc>The pearl monument in the Corniche neighbourhood of Doha, Qatar, illuminated at night with the new high-rises of West Bay in the background -- Jon Hicks/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\PearlMonument20110902</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>LondonSkyline</Name>
    <Date>20110901</Date>
    <Desc>Tower Bridge at night, London -- Jason Hawkes/Getty Images</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\LondonSkyline20110901</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>YunnanProvince</Name>
    <Date>20110831</Date>
    <Desc>Aerial view of rice fields in Yunnan Province, China -- Jialiang Gao/Getty Images</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\YunnanProvince20110831</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>KarnasaiValley</Name>
    <Date>20110830</Date>
    <Desc>Pinnacles of sandstone among orange dunes of the Karnasai Valley, Chad -- George Steinmetz/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\KarnasaiValley20110830</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>SaddlebackCaterpillar</Name>
    <Date>20110829</Date>
    <Desc>Saddleback caterpillar on a leaf in the Cockscomb Basin, Belize -- Frans Lanting/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\SaddlebackCaterpillar20110829</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>NottingHill</Name>
    <Date>20110828</Date>
    <Desc>Notting Hill Carnival, London, England -- Bettina Strenske/Photolibrary</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\NottingHill20110828</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>KeeBeach</Name>
    <Date>20110827</Date>
    <Desc>Wave breaking off Ke'e Beach on Kauai, Hawaii, USA -- Mark A. Johnson/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\KeeBeach20110827</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>ChileVolcano</Name>
    <Date>20110826</Date>
    <Desc>The eruption of Puyehue - Cordon Caulle Rininahue Volcano, Chile -- Ian Salas/Photolibrary</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\ChileVolcano20110826</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>StaghornCoral</Name>
    <Date>20110825</Date>
    <Desc>Staghorn coral, Great Barrier Reef, off the coast of Australia -- Frans Lanting/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\StaghornCoral20110825</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>LacewingEggs</Name>
    <Date>20110824</Date>
    <Desc>Green lacewing eggs -- Charles Melton/Visuals Unlimited</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\LacewingEggs20110824</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>Happisburgh</Name>
    <Date>20110823</Date>
    <Desc>Sea walls built off the coast of Happisburgh, England -- Tim Harris</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\Happisburgh20110823</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>OatHarvest</Name>
    <Date>20110822</Date>
    <Desc>Combine harvesting oats surrounded by a corn field in Wisconsin -- Richard Hamilton Smith/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\OatHarvest20110822</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>CasaresSpain</Name>
    <Date>20110821</Date>
    <Desc>The white village of Casares, Spain -- Jose Fuste Raga/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\CasaresSpain20110821</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>NebutsujiTemple</Name>
    <Date>20110820</Date>
    <Desc>Stone statues in Otagi Nenbutsu-ji Temple in Kyoto, Japan -- Rudy Sulgan/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\NebutsujiTemple20110820</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>AfricanElephant</Name>
    <Date>20110819</Date>
    <Desc>Juvenile African elephant with cattle egrets -- Anup Shah/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\AfricanElephant20110819</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>AircraftBoneyard</Name>
    <Date>20110818</Date>
    <Desc>Jet aircraft on the tarmac of the Davis-Monthan Air Force Base in Tucson, Arizona, USA -- Jay Dickman/Corbis</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\AircraftBoneyard20110818</Url>
  </Picture>
  <Picture>
    <Name>GuilinFisherman</Name>
    <Date>20110817</Date>
    <Desc>Fisherman near Guilin, China -- SIME / eStock Photo</Desc>
    <Url>ArtGalleryPhotos\GuilinFisherman20110817</Url>
  </Picture>
</ArrayOfPicture>
```

Comment: Post all your code. The `query` variable is missing, and the `select new Picture` statement doesn't make sense at all!

Comment: Claus thanks for your comment (apologies i missed it yesterday!).  I have modified my copy & paste error.  Also added comments below which add to the commentary

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted is incomplete; what is `query`? Your LINQ query should look like this:

```
var pictures = from p in loadedData.Descendants( "Picture" )
               select new Picture() {
                 Name = (string)p.Element("Name"),
                 Date = (string)p.Element("Date"),                  
                 Url = (string)p.Element("Url"),
               };
```

or

```
var pictures = from p in loadedData.Root.Elements( "Picture" )
               select new Picture() {
                 Name = (string)p.Element("Name"),
                 Date = (string)p.Element("Date"),                  
                 Url = (string)p.Element("Url"),
               };
```

The above code assumes you have a class called `Picture` containing the properties `Name`, `Date` & `Url`.

Comment: Praetorian - apologies I made a copy and paste error.  I have corrected this as you can see in the original above, and therefore it now reads simialr to your answer.  The key here however is that neither loadedData.Root.Elements("Picture") or loadedData.Descendants("Picture") returns anything while in debug mode (ie if you watch them, they return 'null'.... thanks for your help...

Comment: @Tim Windsor: My guess is the document itself is not being loaded. Add a breakpoint after the `XDocument.Load` line and watch it in the debugger window. If it loads correctly you should be able to see the entire contents of the XML file. I tried out the above code in a WPF project (don't have the Windows Phone compiler installed on this machine) and both versions work just fine. How is the XML file making it into IsolatedStorage in the first place?

Comment: the document I pasted above is the contents of the XDocument variable (loadedData).  This is why I'm confused.  The XML document is created using the XmlSerializer of a list of Picture class (i have created)....

Comment: @Tim Windsor: Try removing the schema namespace declarations from the root element. Silverlight doesn't support schema validation so they're useless on the phone anyway, maybe that's what's messing with the parsing.